# How Can I get the output blob of an audio file when apply some effect using Pedalboard.js Library?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I'm using [Pedalboard Js](https://github.com/dashersw/pedalboard.js) that is a library for process audio through `Web Audio API`.
I want to get the output blob of a specific arrange of the pedals, how can I do that? I don't see any method that make that function (extract/export the blob), is that possible?

Comment: What is this "output blob"?  Is it the audio that you would get for an arrangement of the pedals?  Or do you want the actual settings of the pedals?

Comment: @RaymondToy The audio that you get for an arrangement of the pedals.

Comment: I think you can use MediaRecorder to save the audio.  Recorder.js might work too.  Note: I have not used either.